# maps multiple pairs in c++

Tags: c++, maps

i need to read a csv file which it has lines like this:

SR000001,surname 0001,name 0001

i have created my own string class and i want to insert the data in a

```
std::map<char*,<char*,char*>> students;
```

i have tried the following but i am getting errors.

(myString.getName returns a char* pointer)

```
myString am;
     myString name;
           myString surname;
           char* ptr;
           ptr = strtok ( buffer , ",");
           int i=0;
           while ( ptr != NULL )
           {
               i++;
               if ( i == 1 )
               {
                   am.setName(ptr);
               }
               if ( i == 2 )
               {
                   surname.setName(ptr);
               }
               if ( i == 3)
               {
                   name.setName(ptr);
                   students.insert(make_pair(am.getName(),make_pair(name.getName(),surname.getName())));
               }
           }
           am.clear();
           name.clear();
           surname.clear();
```

Comment: First, `<char*,char*>` is not a valid C++ type. You are probably looking at `std::tuple`. Second, you do not want `char*` anywhere in your program. Use `std::string`. If you are absolutely sure that your own string class works, and for some reason unknown to science you want to use it, then use it **in** the `map`. The only place you should ever use `char*` is inside your string code.

Comment: *"i have created my own string class..."* **Stop right there.** Even if you're sure you want to do that, you are now trying to solve two difficult problems at once. The problem could be in your string class, or in the code that tries to use it. Separate these problems: test your string class by itself and develop your file-sifting code with `std::string`, and don't combine them until they both work perfectly.

Comment: i am not allowed to use std::string anywhere in my program. it is a univesity assignment

Comment: That's unfortunate, `std::string` is the better option. But the advice still stands. Implement this problem using `string` first, and when you're sure it's working, replace it with your custom string class.